# Use Open Distro security plugin in regular Elastic stack

Tags: elasticsearch, active-directory, ldap, kibana, elasticsearch-opendistro

I was trying to find an opensource plugin to use LDAP/AD authentication for Elasticsearch/Kibana. I found Open Distro which is currently based on Elasticsearch 7.10.2, and I wanted to use the security plugin in my existing regular ES stack which works with 7.11.2, but it complains that it can't work with newer versions of ES. The problem is that I cant downgrade anyway without losing my data.

Is there another way (opensource) to integrate LDAP whether using Open Disto or another plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "downgrade" in that case if you want to stick with the latest version of this plugin I think.

You could start a new cluster with 7.10.2 and use reindex from remote to reindex your data in the "new" cluster. So read from 7.11 and write to 7.10.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. After trying in different ways this was the best option!

Comment: Out of curiosity what feature are you using which is not available in elasticsearch 7.13?

Comment: LDAP integration as a cost-free solution.

Comment: I see. Indeed this one is only available from Platinum level license.